# spl-token: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, unix, rust, solana, libssl

Im having an issue on my aws instance,
After running spl-token with any arg, I get the following error

`spl-token: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I thought that maybe it has somethin to do with my shared libraries,

so after running
`ldconfig -p | grep libssl`

This is what I get

```
        libssl3.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl3.so
        libssl.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.3
        libssl.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so
```

What I notice is that there is no `libssl.so.1.1` listed, does that account for the error?

So next I searched for how to add libssl.so.1.1 to the shared libs,
I found an article saying you have to edit /etc/ld.so.conf.d/.conf and add the path to the lib.
So I created the file and added the path /snap/core18/2344/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1.

No success

Comment: I try this solution https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403778/upgrading-to-ubuntu-22-04-causes-libcrypto-errors-apt-dpkg-broken And it works fine for me

Answer (score -2):

I managed to fix the issue by running everything locally rather than on my ec2 instance. I know its not the solution to the problem, but perhaps consider switching the environment as a solution